# How can I find out if my (Wi-Fi) adapter supports dual band?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My Lonovo Yoga 11S laptop has a Realtek RTL8723AU Wi-Fi 802.11n USB 2.0 adapter. But surprisingly, with this information I cannot find if it supports dual band or not. Is there a better way to find if it supports dual band?

(I need the information because I am considering change to a dual band modem since the internet speed at home is frustratingly slow.)

Specs: Windows 8.1; Lenovo Yoga 11S; Wi-Fi Adapter: Realtek RTL8723AU

Answer (score 2):

If they're too embarrassed to say, it's almost certainly 2.4GHz-only (b/g/n).

Looking at Yoga 11s information on Lenovo's website, it only says b/g/n, not a/b/g/n, and it makes no mention of 5GHz or dual-band, so it's almost certainly 2.4GHz-only.